# How to create database of VIEW table in Django models?

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
CREATE TABLE banks (
    name character varying(49),
    id bigint NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE branches (
    ifsc character varying(11) NOT NULL,
    bank_id bigint,
    branch character varying(74),
    address character varying(195),
    city character varying(50),
    district character varying(50),
    state character varying(26)
);

CREATE VIEW bank_branches AS
 SELECT branches.ifsc,
    branches.bank_id,
    branches.branch,
    branches.address,
    branches.city,
    branches.district,
    branches.state,
    banks.name AS bank_name
   FROM (branches
     JOIN banks ON ((branches.bank_id = banks.id)));
```

I created Django models of an existing DB through this way:
`python manage.py inspectdb > models.py` But It wasn't created models of `Database bank_branches VIEW table` which I want to know how to write, `database bank_branches VIEW`  models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the option to include views:

```
python manage.py inspectdb --include-views > models.py
```

Read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb).